# Moving ellipse moves other elements in QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm writing a simple gui with a `QGraphicsScene`. Inside this scene i have 2 simple XY axis and I have a function to retrieve the position of my mouse click on the scene.

I added a simple movable ellipse to my scene and I'm retrieving it's position (at the moment it's only an on click detection, later I will implement a signal for its movement)

Here's the code:

**View.py**:

```
import math
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QPointF
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPainterPath
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsItem,
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QSizeGrip
)
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene): # Used to indicate inheritance from parent class
    clicked = Signal(QPointF)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        l = min(rect.width(), rect.height()) / 30

        x_left = QPointF(rect.left(), 0)
        x_right = QPointF(rect.right(), 0)
        painter.drawLine(x_left, x_right)

        right_triangle = QPainterPath()
        right_triangle.lineTo(-0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l, 0.5 * l)
        right_triangle.lineTo(-0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l, -0.5 * l)
        right_triangle.closeSubpath()
        right_triangle.translate(x_right)

        painter.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        painter.drawPath(right_triangle)

        y_top = QPointF(0, rect.top())
        y_bottom = QPointF(0, rect.bottom())
        painter.drawLine(y_top, y_bottom)

        top_triangle = QPainterPath()
        top_triangle.lineTo(.5*l, -0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l)
        top_triangle.lineTo(-.5*l, -0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l)
        top_triangle.closeSubpath()
        top_triangle.translate(y_bottom)

        painter.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        painter.drawPath(top_triangle)



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        sp = event.scenePos()
        self.clicked.emit(sp)
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class MyView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("8D.me")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 500)

        self.btn = QPushButton("test2")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet( "color: white; border-radius: 4px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); background: rgb(66, 184, 221); min-width:100px;min-height:30px")

        self.view = QGraphicsView()

        print(self.view.size())
        self.view.scale(1, -1)
        self.scene = GraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setIcon()
        self.ellipse=self.scene.addEllipse(10,10,10,10)
        self.ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        #flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        #self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.scene.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_clicked(self, p):
        print("position",self.ellipse.pos())
        print("clicked", p.x(), p.y())
        print(self.view.size())

# Insert methods for creating/adding elements to the default view.
# Mehods....
    def setIcon(self):
        appIcon = QIcon('logo')
        self.setWindowIcon(appIcon)

#Insert here the public methods called by the Controller to update the view
```

****main**.py:**

```
import View
#import Model
#import Controller

#Useful example: https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/
def main():
    """Main function."""
    # Create an instance of QApplication
    app = QApplication([])

    # Show the GUI
    mainwindow =View.MyView()
    mainwindow.show()

    # Create instances of model and controller
    #model = Model.myModel()
    #Controller.myController(view=mainwindow,model=model)
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT:** I added also the `main` code. I have the View in a separate file since I am using a MVC design pattern.

My GUI looks like this:

[image]

And it works so far.

The problem is if I move the ellipse (which moves correctly) my XY axis moves too, and I can't figure out why.

For example this is how my GUI changes if I move the ellipse toward the upper right angle:

[image]

What's the problem? How do I "fix" the XY axis? I would like to keep my axis still and move only the ellipse inside the scene region.

Comment: please provide a [mre]. I also have a question since your requirements are not precise, how much area do you want to show in the QGraphicsView? A simple example to understand how Qt Graphics Framework works is to understand it as QGraphicsScene is the world and QGraphicsView as a camera, so the camera to observe a part of the world has to change its region of interest, in your case what is that region of interest?

Comment: I edited the code adding also the main code to launch the view. Anyway, what I would like to get is the first image I posted. Basically I would like to have exactly what has been shown in that image and then move the ellipse around, without moving also my axis. So far i'm able to move my ellipse, but also my axis move.
I used some prints to debug and i noticed that rect.left() and rect.right() values changes as i move my ellipse, thus the drawBackground function draws my lines in a new position.

Comment: Okay, I'll explain in more detail so that you understand me: The QGraphicsView (the camera) shows a piece of the QGraphicsScene (world), for example let's assume that it initially shows the topbottom rectangle (-100, -100) and size ( 200, 200) because the (0, 0) will be in the center (which is the crossing of the lines), let's say you drag the item to position 150, 150 that is outside the rectangle and then at that moment what rectangle should be displayed? Should only a specific rectangle be displayed even though items are moved? If so, then what size should it be?

Comment: I shouldnt be able to drag my item outside of the box. So if i have my view of (200,200), i shouldn't be able to drag my item outside of that view. I would like to move my ellipse just inside that view and to keep the axis still. I tried to set some properties like setGeometry and SetFixedSize, but I didn't solve the problem. 
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naHtXpCiPuM&list=PL1FgJUcJJ03uO70zDLDF3oaTu6s2QLOPa&index=61 But it has the same problem i'm trying to solve. As he moves the circle, the view "expands" with the scroll

Comment: I'm sorry for my inexperience, but i'm just starting and trying to figure out how the framework works

Comment: It seems i solved the problem by adding:  

 ```self.view.setFixedSize(600,480) 
     self.view.setSceneRect(-300,-220,600,480)
     self.view.fitInView(0,0,600,480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio) ```

Comment: If you have found your solution then you must publish it explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem following this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/48564/force-qgraphicsview-size-to-match-qgraphicsscene-size/7

Basically i added the following lines to my code:

```
self.view.setFixedSize(600,480)       
self.view.setSceneRect(-300,-220,600,480)      
self.view.fitInView(0,0,600,480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

So the new **View.py** is:

```
import math
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QPointF, Qt
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPainterPath
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsItem,
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QSizeGrip
)
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene): # Used to indicate inheritance from parent class
    clicked = Signal(QPointF)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        #print('Pinto rect',rect.width(),rect.height())
        l = min(rect.width(), rect.height()) / 30
        #print('printo l',l)

        #Qui c'è il bug. La funzione drawbackground viene chiamata a ogni modifica della scene.
        #Lo starting point del drawing della line cambia nel tempo, ecco perchè mi si spostano gli assi
        x_left = QPointF(rect.left(), 0)
        x_right = QPointF(rect.right(), 0)
        print('printo gli x',rect.left(),rect.height())
        painter.drawLine(x_left, x_right)

        right_triangle = QPainterPath()
        right_triangle.lineTo(-0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l, 0.5 * l)
        right_triangle.lineTo(-0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l, -0.5 * l)
        right_triangle.closeSubpath()
        right_triangle.translate(x_right)

        painter.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        painter.drawPath(right_triangle)

        y_top = QPointF(0, rect.top())
        y_bottom = QPointF(0, rect.bottom())
        painter.drawLine(y_top, y_bottom)

        top_triangle = QPainterPath()
        top_triangle.lineTo(.5*l, -0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l)
        top_triangle.lineTo(-.5*l, -0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l)
        top_triangle.closeSubpath()
        top_triangle.translate(y_bottom)

        painter.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        painter.drawPath(top_triangle)



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        sp = event.scenePos()
        self.clicked.emit(sp)
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class MyView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("8D.me")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 500)

        self.btn = QPushButton("test2")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet( "color: white; border-radius: 4px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); background: rgb(66, 184, 221); min-width:100px;min-height:30px")

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        print(self.view.size())

        self.view.setFixedSize(600,480)
        self.view.setSceneRect(-300,-220,590,470)
        self.view.fitInView(0,0,600,480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        self.view.scale(1, -1)
        self.scene = GraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setIcon()
        self.ellipse=self.scene.addEllipse(-5,-5,10,10)
        self.ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        #flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        #self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.scene.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_clicked(self, p):
        print("position",self.ellipse.pos())
        print("clicked", p.x(), p.y())
        print(self.view.size())

# Insert methods for creating/adding elements to the default view.
# Mehods....
    def setIcon(self):
        appIcon = QIcon('logo')
        self.setWindowIcon(appIcon)

#Insert here the public methods called by the Controller to update the view
```